# how to solve the NaNs produced when i use the log()

Tags: r

```
> LL_LN<-function(para){ 
+   ww=para[1]  # w
+   alpha=para[2]  # alpha  
+   beta=para[3]# beta
+   sigma=para[4]
+   n=length(R)
+   psi <- rep(0, n)
+   # read data from file , named as RR
+   psi[1]=0.5  # replace with mean (R) or R(1) 
+   sum1 = -n/2*log(2*pi*sigma^2)
+   sum4 = -log(R[1])
+   sum3 = -((log(R[1])-log(psi[1]))+0.5*(sigma^2))^2/(2*(sigma^2))
+   sum=0
+   
+   for (i in 2:n) {
+     psi[i]=ww+alpha*psi[i-1]+beta*R[i-1]
+     sum4=sum4-log(R[i])
+     sum3=sum3-((log(R[i])-log(psi[i]))+0.5*(sigma^2))^2/(2*(sigma^2))
+   }
+   sum=sum1+sum3+sum4
+   return(-sum)
+   
+ }
> n=10000
> k=5
> sigma=0.25
> mu=-(sigma^2)/2
> result=c(0,0,0,0)
> output<-matrix(0,k,4)
> output<-as.data.frame(output)
> for(j in 1:k){
+   #E<-rexp(n,1) 
+   E=rlnorm(n,mu,sigma)
+   w=1
+   a=0.2
+   b=0.3
+   R <- rep(0, n) # To Store R1,R2....R1000
+   X <- rep(0, n) # To Store X1,X2....X1000
+   X[1] = 0.5
+   R[1]=X[1]*E[1]
+   
+   for (i in 2:n) # To Find R1,R2....R1000
+   {
+     X[i]=w+a*X[i-1]+b*R[i-1]
+     R[i]=X[i]*E[i]
+   }
+   hist(R)
+   mean(E)
+   
+   initial =c(1,0.2,0.3,2)
+   op<-optim(initial,LL_LN)
+   output$V1[j] <- op$par[1]
+   output$V2[j] <- op$par[2]
+   output$V3[j] <- op$par[3]
+   output$V4[j] <- op$par[4]
+   
+   print(output)
+ }
        
         V1        V2        V3        V4
1 1.0202418 0.1989128 0.2927711 0.2484346
2 0.9725745 0.2159796 0.2970536 0.2529665
3 1.0648460 0.1692719 0.2987034 0.2492417
4 1.0186746 0.1819587 0.3039954 0.2517418
5 1.0022230 0.2103271 0.2858050 0.2484962
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> mean<-cbind(mean(output$V1),mean(output$V2),mean(output$V3),mean(output$V4))
> mean
         [,1]    [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 1.015712 0.19529 0.2956657 0.2501762
```

Comment: `NaNs` would be produced if you feed `log()` with negative values.

Comment: `log1p()` could be a solution (depending on the use case)

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I see `warnings()` but the ending output looks OK. Generating `NaN` values during the course of an optimization procedure is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: > warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
2: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
3: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
4: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
5: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
6: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
7: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
8: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
9: In log(R[i]/psi[i]) : NaNs produced
.........but it doesn't make sense because i used another way( log(R[i])-log(psi[i]) it also showed me the log(psi[i]) NaNs produced. but how come the psi will be negative value